# DB client tool -- To get the error message when open toad oracle client

Tags: oracle, tools, client, toad

I have a serious problem with toad oracle client. I got the error message as following when I open toad client (installed and then opened it):

> Error: No valid Oracle clients found. You need at least one 64-bit
>   client properly configured

Please do me a favor to give me how to deal with this issue or give me any slim clue.

Download from toad official website with 64-bit like as following picture

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7hDegNYzw0) from @Philᵀᴹ, I have done this problem and I will try to list all I know and every step as following content, Hopefully I can help someone who has the same issues.

1. Download and Install [Toad for Oracle v12.10](https://www.toadworld.com/p/downloads)

   [image]
2. Open it you should can not use like as below error message

   [image]
3. Download [Instant Client 12.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

   [image]
4. Unzip it and move it to anywhere you like (for example `C:\app\instantclient_12_2`)

   [image]
5. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System-->Environment Variable to "Add" TNS_ADMIN as like below picture

   [image]
6. The same path to "Edit" Path like as following picture

   [image]

   OK done with toad client

   [image]
7. To move your old `tnsnames.ora` to `C:\app\instantclient_12_2` (for example)

   [image]

   [image]

Done all